# PHP script to read from database

Tags: php, database

I have a database named teste with a table called exemplo with 2 columns (id, nome):
Want a php script to select all the information in the nome column, and echo that information and place them in a txt file. What's wrong in the code?
I can only see the first value and not the second.. And with an infinite loop!

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('teste', $link);

/* Desired */
$file = fopen("myfile.txt","w");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exemplo");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($array) {
  echo $array['nome'];

  fputs($file ,$array['nome']); 
}

mysql_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `mysql_fetch_array` only returns one result at a time, so `$array` is always true. You want this:

```
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $array['nome'];
  fputs($file ,$array['nome']); 
}
```

Comment: and to add a new line and not see line1line2 in a row?

Answer (score 3):

```
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This only fetches one row of results. It doesn't stuff the entire result set into your array. You need to do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['nome'];
   fputs($file, $row['nome']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign `$array` once and than loop over it in `while($array)` so this keeps running and running as `$array` is unchanged!
Try changing your code like that:

```
<?php

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
        if (!$link) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db('teste', $link);

        /* Desired */

        $file = fopen("myfile.txt","w");

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exemplo");
        while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $array['nome'];

        fputs($file ,$array['nome']); }
        mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Remove the `;` from the `while` loop condition. `while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result);)`

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns a single row. You need to call it in a loop:

```
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $array['nome'], "\n";
    // do more stuff
}
```

Comment: and to add a new line and not see line1line2 in a row?

Comment: for that you need to add a line separator yourself

Answer (score 0):

This should work. you were leaving `fputs` out of the data loop.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('teste', $link);

/* Desired */

$file = fopen("myfile.txt","w");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exemplo");
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $array['nome'];
    fputs($file, $array['nome'] ."\n");
}

mysql_close($link);
```